# result of pandas.PeriodIndex(astype(str)) in pandas 0.18

Tags: pandas, datetime

Trying to understand what pandas0.18 is telling me by way of the column names when I do the following:

```
import pandas as pd
rng = pd.date_range('1/1/2011', periods=4, freq='Q')
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=pd.to_datetime(rng).to_period('Q'))
df2=pd.DataFrame(columns=df.columns.values.astype(str))
df2
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [164, 165, 166, 167]
Index: []
```

Using a later version, this yields the expected:

```
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [2011Q1, 2011Q2, 2011Q3, 2011Q4]
Index: []
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The integers are the number of units (in this case, quarters) since the reference timestamp.  Default is Unix reference (01-01-1970).  See the `origin` argument in [`to_datetime()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html) for more on reference choices.

For example, using Pandas 0.20.3:

```
pd.to_datetime(pd.date_range('1/1/2011', periods=4, freq='Q')).to_period('Q').astype(int)
# Int64Index([164, 165, 166, 167], dtype='int64')

pd.to_datetime(pd.date_range('1/1/1970', periods=4, freq='Q')).to_period('Q').astype(int)
# Int64Index([0, 1, 2, 3], dtype='int64')
```